# How to do spell check using whoosh python library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, spell-checking, whoosh

How to perform spell checking using whoosh library? I have added some code which is there in documentation. but it is not correcting words. Please find my code.

```
def main():
    print " Hi"

    schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT)
    ix = create_in("/home/praveen/Downloads/who", schema)
    writer = ix.writer()
    writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a", content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
    writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path=u"/b",content=u"The second one is even more interesting!")
    writer.commit()

    qstring = "frm indea wroking for campany"
    qp = qparser.QueryParser("content", ix.schema)
    q = qp.parse(qstring)
    # Try correcting the query
    with ix.searcher() as s:
            corrected = s.correct_query(q,qstring)
            print(corrected)
            print(corrected.query)
            if corrected.query != q:
                print("Did you mean:", corrected.string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();
```

and my output is :

```
 Hi
Correction(And([Term('content', u'frm'), Term('content', u'indea'), Term('content', u'wroking'), Term('content', u'campany')]), 'frm indea wroking for campany')
(content:frm AND content:indea AND content:wroking AND content:campany)
```

I am not getting "Did you mean :" with corrected string.

Comment: Then obviously `corrected.query == q`.

Comment: what changes need to be done in my program . I took the code from documentation. input is qstring  which should undergo spell check

Answer (score 1):

The script gets correction only from the indexed words. The phrase you want to correct has no similar words in the index.

Your phrase:

> "frm indea wroking for campany"

Indexed phrases:

> "This is the first document we've added!"
>
> "The second one is even more interesting!"

If you give a phrase like: `"secend one is ewen"`
you will get:

```
('Did you mean:', u'second one is even')
```

It is well corrected.